# Do C/C++ compilers such as GCC generally optimize modulo by a constant power of 2?

Tags: gcc, constants, compiler-optimization, modulo, compile-time-constant

Let's say I have something like:

```
#define SIZE 32

/* ... */

unsigned x;

/* ... */

x %= SIZE;
```

Would the `x % 32` generally be reduced to `x & 31` by most C/C++ compilers such as GCC?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Whoops, I meant `x % 32` and `x & 31`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, any respectable compiler should perform this optimization.  Specifically, a `% X` operation, where `X` is a *constant power of two* will become the equivalent of an `& (X-1)` operation.

GCC will even do this with optimizations turned off:

Example (`gcc -c -O0` version 3.4.4 on Cygwin):

```
unsigned int test(unsigned int a) {
   return a % 32;
}
```

Result (objdump -d):

```
00000000 <_test>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   6:   5d                      pop    %ebp
   7:   83 e0 1f                and    $0x1f,%eax          ;; Here
   a:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: Would it do that without optimizations enabled just like it reduces `(5 + 5)` to `10`?

Comment: @Matt Updated. Yes, GCC does. Also, showing you these commands should empower you to try any ideas like this out yourself.

Comment: Trying it myself will only tell me about my particular implementation.

Comment: Common misconception here ... `-O0` doesn’t disable optimizations in GCC. [The GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) says that `-O0` will _reduce compilation time and make debugging produce the expected results_. For example, on GCC Debian 6.3.0, `gcc -O0 -Q --help=optimizers | grep enabled | wc -l` suggests that 53 optimizations remain enabled.